# 標準入力と引数のどちらにも対応したbourne-shellスクリプト

Tags: sh

標準入力が与えられた場合はそちらを行ごとに、そうでない場合は引数をまるまる1行として扱うスクリプトを作ろうとしています。

```sh
#!/bin/sh

fetch_input () {
    [ -t 0 ] && echo "$1" || cat -
}

fetch_input "$*" | while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "reading: $line"
done
```

標準入力が存在するかチェックするのに上のように`[ -t 0]`を使用すると大抵の場合はうまくいくのですが、インタラクティブシェルで動かすことが前提になるため、sshなどでリモートマシンのスクリプトを動かそうとすると`-t`オプションで仮想端末を用意する必要がでてしまいます。

```sh
ssh -t remote '/path/to/script.sh foo bar'
```

この場合、もっと単純に標準入力と引数のどちらにも対応できるスクリプトを書く方法はありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

普通※は引数の有無で判定します。（※例：`cat`）
`$#` で引数の数が分かるので↓とか

```
{ test $# = 0 && cat || echo "$*"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

別解です。
変数の展開機能を利用して、引数がない場合は標準入力(`cat`の実行結果の置換)、あれば引数を使用する。

```
${@:-"`cat`"}
```

`bash`ならば次の例も使えます。

```
${@:-"$(cat)"}
```

【使用例】

```
printf "%s"  ${@:-"`cat`"}
```